# Add B to List<A<object>>, where B implements A with a value type

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, covariance

Given the following types and snippet:

```
interface IFoo<out T> {
    T doThing();
}

class Bar : IFoo<int> {
    int doThing() => 0;
}

var list = new List<IFoo<object>> {
    new Bar() //fails to compile
};
```

I understand that it's not possible to add a `Bar` to a `List<IFoo<object>>`, because `Bar`'s `T` is a value type.

Given that I need to `IFoo` type-safe, how can I change `Bar` or the collection so that it's possible to store both `IFoo<T>` for some value and reference types?

Comment: How do you plan to use the collection?

Comment: @GuruStron only to access the `doThing`. Clearly it would be unsafe to extract a item with a specific type argument from it. Type-safety on `IFoo` is reserved for places that directly manipulate them, I'm fine with losing that safety once it is stored in the collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically I see only one option here:

```
    public interface IFoo<out T>:IFoo
    {
        T doThing();
    }

    public interface IFoo
    {
        object doThing();
    }

    public class Bar : IFoo<int>
    {
        public int doThing(){return 0;}
        object IFoo.doThing()
        {
            return doThing();
        }
    }

    var list = new List<IFoo> 
    {
        new Bar()
    };
```

Comment: Seems legitimate, that's exactly how the two standard `IEnumerable` interfaces (generic and not) work. I'll hold the accept for a while to not discourage alternative solutions.